# How to use MEF to init a group of classes?

Tags: dependency-injection, prism, mef

I use prism/mvvm/mef for my app, and loading all Views marked with ViewExport(Region) does work nicely (I'm using the StockTraderRI AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehaviour).

Now I'd like to use this runtime lookup capability to initialise some other background classes.

Say I got an interface

```
public interface ITable
{
}
```

And I got a lot of classes deriving from this interface.

Is there a way to mark those derived classes somehow and get MEF to create them on runtime and add them into some kind of list or container?

Like into a region which is not shown anywhere, I'd expect? How would I achieve this in MEF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is!
Mark the classes inheriting your interface with Export attribute and in another class create yourself a property say of generic type ObservableCollection with attribute [ImportMany]. The should do the trick.

Comment: Thats all? But how does MEF know which things belong into which collection? By the generic type?

Comment: Yes actually your different classes will be decorated with [Export(typeof(ITable))] and MEF will be looking for any class that inherits or corresponds to the generic type to satisfy your collection, create instances and add them to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MEF instead Unity you can also use Container call within your bootstrapper :

```
var tables = Container.GetExportedValues<ITable>();
```

Container is the public property of your MEFBootstrapper.

Comment: it is the alternative dependency injection container. MEF is my preference though.